# File too big when using plotly::api_create and ggplot2::geom_sf functions

Tags: r, plotly, shapefile, r-sf

I am trying to make online plotting of spatial data using plotly in R but I got an error message "Request Entity Too Large This file is too big! Your current subscription is limited to 524 KB uploads." Any clue about how to solve that? In oder to reproduce my code, you need to (i) register on [plotly](https://plot.ly/) and (ii) download shapefiles of French departments available on my [github repo](https://github.com/mblumuga/frenchelection2017/tree/master/data/shapefile). The 3 files should be in a folder that is named *shapefile*. It seems to me that is the *ggplot2* function *geom_sf* that produces files that are too large. My code is below

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggplot2)

#Info required for online plotting 
Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="replace_by_your_username")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="replace_by_your_apikey")

#Read shapefile
dep <- sf::st_read("replace_with_the_correctPATH/shapefile/DEPARTEMENT.shp")

#Variable to plot
zz<-runif(length(dep$CODE_DEPT),-10,3)

#ggplot2 object
gg <- dep %>%
mutate(discrete = cut(zz, c(-10, seq(-3, 3, by = 1)))) %>%
ggplot() +
geom_sf(aes(fill = discrete, text = paste("Department:", dep$CODE_DEPT, "<br>", "bli", zz))) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "PuOr", name = "bla")

#Plotting the figure on your local computer works
#plotly::ggplotly(gg, tooltip = c("text"))

#Generate an error message
plotly::api_create(gg, tooltip = c("text"),filename = "sthing")
```

Comment: Are there any reasons to use {plotly} instead of {leaflet} for showing your map ? You would also have the interactivity and background image as a bonus.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know {leaflet}. Since I asked my question, I have found a pure [ggplot solution](https://colinfay.me/mapping-the-french-second-round-results-with-r/) avoiding shapefiles reading the blog of Colin Fay. However, the projection of France does not look as nice as in the code provided above.

Comment: You need to be careful with projections, in particular with `sf`. You need to specify the `crs` in `coord_sf`. Look at my introduction to mapping with {sf} in English or French: https://statnmap.com/2018-07-14-introduction-to-mapping-with-sf-and-co/

Comment: By the way, if you really want to do it with plotly, you should try plotly syntax directly with `plot_geo` : https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be your issue but I experienced the same thing. For future readers, my issue seemed to be that the dataframe I was using (say, 100 rows) was subset from a large dataset (15,000 rows) which was larger than the file limit.

Although my subset was quite small and well within the upload limit, I had to save the subset as a csv, load it back in and use that new loaded dataframe as my plotly upload. Even though the imported dataframe was the same row count as the subset dataframe, I had to break the subset connection to the original larger dataset, don't know why.